# Offset direction stops working when I get too close

Tags: 2d, game-maker, debugging

I have a script trying to get the gun aim at the target instead of the origin:

[image]

It's partially working.

[image]

but when I get too close with the mouse the player starts spinning

I would appreciate a help regarding why it happens and how to fix it.

Comment: I have reuploaded the images to stack's imgur service, available from one of the tools in the question text toolbox. Please use this service as other services do not guarantee that the image will remain available for life. And if the images become unavailable, your question becomes much unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `image_angle` (the current rotation) to calculate the new rotation for your character, this is what's making it spin - it just keeps summing every frame.

If your goal is to make the character's weapon point at the mouse, take a look at the answers [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133977/how-can-i-rotate-an-object-based-on-anothers-offset-to-it).