# Rotate the parent object so that the child object points to the cursor 2D

Tags: mathematics, rotation, aiming

I have an arm that has a pivot point on it. I want to rotate the arm so that the barrel of the gun points to the cursor. How do I calculate the angle of rotation for the arm?
I'm not very good at math :)
[image: arm]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I rotate an object based on another's offset to it?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/133977/39518)

Comment: If you need something different from the answers at that link, or have trouble implementing them, please edit your question to clarify what you need that's different and we can re-open this question for new answers.

Comment: @DMGregory, thanks for the link!  It's just what I need